# What does 'for someone else's views' mean?

Tags: prepositions

The original sentence is 'Ajjawi’s visa was canceled and he was summarily deported — for someone else’s views.'. I want to know what is the meaning of "for someone else's views".And how explains the use of 'for'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phrase beginning with "for" can give a reason:

> He was arrested for stealing a book.

The phrase "someone else's views" is completely literal. But "views" means "opinions".

So Ajjawi was deported, and the reason was not Ajjawi's actions, the reason was somebody else's opinions.  The sentence doesn't give any more details.

This looks like a teaser or "clickbait".  It is intended to make you wonder "How did that happen? Who was the "someone"? What were their opinions?" and then read the full article.

Comment: Context: Ajjawi arrived in Boston, intending to study at Harvard, and immigration officers, allegedly, took his phone and found, in his friends list, the names of people who, they said, had said bad things about the US. For this reason they deemed him "inadmissible". That's the [story](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/2019/8/27/incoming-freshman-deported/), which is in the Harvard Crimson,